# Cannot get installed apps for user | Microsoft Graph API

Tags: c#, .net, microsoft-graph-api

My application should retrieve all installed apps for every user in the AAD.

According to this [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/userteamwork-list-installedapps?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) the application permissions are:

```
TeamsAppInstallation.ReadForUser.All,
TeamsAppInstallation.ReadWriteSelfForUser.All, 
TeamsAppInstallation.ReadWriteForUser.All
```

The endpoint I'm calling is

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{user-id}/teamwork/installedApps
```

or in .net:

```
var options = new TokenCredentialOptions { AuthorityHost = AzureAuthorityHosts.AzurePublicCloud };

var authProvider = new ClientSecretCredential(_tenantId, _clientId, _clientSecret, options);

GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(authProvider);

var apps = await graphClient.Users[id.ToString()].Teamwork.InstalledApps.Request().GetAsync();
```

It doesnt matter which permission I configure, I always get following error:

```
Microsoft.Graph.ServiceException: 'Code: AuthenticationError Message: Error authenticating with resource
```

Comment: Validate your token whether all required permissions are adding to token or not. Use https://jwt.ms/ to validate the token.

Answer (score 0):

would you check with your admin whether you have a valid subscription for this user? at the same time you can also check the same API on graph explorer - https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer .

Comment: There is a valid subscription. I can get all other endpoints I need, but this specific one seems to not work.

Comment: have you tried the same endpoint in graph explore as well ?

Comment: yes, did not work out either

Comment: What error you are getting on graph explorer side ?